# Is there a fate worse than oblivion?

Tags: depression, aversion

Is there a fate worse than [*oblivion*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/oblivion)?

To forget, to be forgotten is there  … Chant for anti-[*nothingless*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nothingless)?

Comment: This site is really a joke and is completely dead, and I still didn't write the details(one day ı can ;)) but it is funny that a huge community's site is in the hands of such a "personality" LOL

Comment: Yes. There is a fate worse than oblivion. It is suffering that never ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The opportunity afforded by human life is rare and precious. To embrace oblivion as a human would be...sad.

[SN56.47](http://suttacentral.net/sn56.47/en/sujato)

> “Mendicants, suppose a person was to throw a yoke with a single hole into the ocean. And there was a one-eyed turtle who popped up once every hundred years.
>   What do you think, mendicants?
>   Would that one-eyed turtle, popping up once every hundred years, still poke its neck through the hole in that yoke?”
>
> “Only after a very long time, sir, if ever.”
>
> “That one-eyed turtle would poke its neck through the hole in that yoke sooner than a fool who has fallen to the underworld would be reborn as a human being, I say.

Also see [DN23](http://suttacentral.net/dn23/en/sujato) on Nihilism:

> Nihilism
>
> Seated to one side, the chieftain Pāyāsi said to Venerable Kassapa the Prince:
>   “Master Kassapa, this is my doctrine and view:
>   ‘There’s no afterlife. No beings are reborn spontaneously. There’s no fruit or result of good and bad deeds.’”
>
> “Well, chieftain, I’ve never seen or heard of anyone holding such a doctrine or view.
>
> For how on earth can anyone say such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

The worst fate is an important person, famous, who is known as a "good person" by most of the people but in reality is deeply corrupted is exposed to the public with all of the details. That ego crushing experience would be a really horrible thing that a person can ever experience. Probably that is far worse than oblivion or anything else ;)

Answer (score 0):

No, there are less fates similar danger as Nihilism, householder Oni, interested.

One should not for get (how things came up rightly) and so there will be soon forgiviness out of serious truthfulness that does not take side but resolves toward good direction ond goes on.

[Verdrängen ist nicht Verzeihen](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,805.msg2491.html#msg2491)

There is a [chant](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/dhammayut/chanting_en.html#refuge): Bowing down, I [ask for forgiviness](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/dhammayut/chanting_en.html#forgiveness) of what ever foolish I had done toward my parents, teacher, the Juwels. To the Buddha, I go for refuge, to the Dhamma, I take refuge, to the Sangha of his Bhikkhus, I take refuge, I resolve in not taking existence, I resolve to take not what is not given, I resolve to do not engage in harmful and disturbing sense pleasure (of flesh), I resolve in speaking truthful, I resolve not to take indoxications causing heedlessness.

After that: [The Sublime Attitudes](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/dhammayut/chanting_en.html#sublime) and at the end of this auspicious merits [Dedication of Merits](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/dhammayut/chanting_en.html#merit).

That is a huge antitude to oblivion, Nihilism and vi-bhava-tanha. Not to mention that once having refuge the tripple Gems protect and one is no more left alone, even if it might appear outwardly this way.

*[Not for trade, exchange, stacks and bonds to the world, but for liberation]*